# Firefox without same origin policy

Tags: firefox, iframe

I have an increasingly frustrating problem with the firefox implementation of the same origin policy.

I am developing an integrated system with touch screen support, and we have the user option of loading web pages in iframes in several locations on the screen. The web pages can be **any** kind of webpages from any kind of domain and location (google, yahoo, intranet pages etc) and herein lies my problem.

I need to be able to add an onclick event to the iframe, that gives me the id of the iframe (or some other unique identifier) as a response. This tells me that activity (web browsing) is underway on the iframe and that the iframe should not be reloaded (the pages are set for a fixed automatic update interval that should be interrupted on activity.

I have read just about everything google returns me (but I would love to be disproven in this matter) and I have found this to be the best (among a lot of other) solution:

```
<iframe src='http://google.com' id='iframe1' onload='netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite"); this.contentWindow.document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {alert(this.id);}, false)'></iframe>
```

This just gives me the regular **permission denied for http://localhost to get property Window.document from http://google.com**

I know **why** I get this error message, and my question is simple. How do I remove it?

It is an integrated system, I can compile firefox from source, I can edit the source code if needed, I can change prefs.js etc. but I need to use firefox (I know all other sensible web browsers has a nice command line switch to turn it off...) but we have a (quite) tight integration with the firefox platform that would be hard to remove.

We currently use Firefox v.3.5.16 (I know it's EOL, we are going to upgrade it some other time) on a Debian Squeeze platform. If needed I can upgrade to a newer Firefox version, but from what I have found it seems to fare even worse in this matter.

**TL;DR**
Help me to shut of same origin policy, in **any way possible** on Firefox 3.5.16 for an integrated platform that needs to alter code through cross domain iframes.

Comment: Oh, and just to clarify it **only** needs to work in firefox. Just any solution at all would suffice at this stage!

Comment: [Can I disable SOP (Same Origin Policy) on any browser for development?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/330427/can-i-disable-sop-same-origin-policy-on-any-browser-for-development) and most likely: [XMLHttpRequest send function throws 0x80004005 exception when called from local html file as of Gecko 5 even with UniversalBrowserRead requested](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=667312)

Comment: My supplied code example uses the first link (and I have tried the CORS addon) to no use, it's still not working! The other link is for Firefox 5, where enablePrivilege is removed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel quite stupid.

It works when you use **UniversalXPConnect** instead of UniversalBrowserWrite.

For example:
netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");

Also, you can **not** use this.id or this.parentNode.id, that still gives a (different) access error. To defeat that problem just store it in a temporary variable first:

```
onload='var tempstuff = this.id; this.contentWindow.document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {alert(tempstuff);}, false)'
```

Comment: This answers my own question, no further responses are needed! If anyone could mark this question as answered I would appreciate it (I can't mark my own answer for two days).

Comment: Then you have to wait, I can't marked it either ;)

Comment: Doest that still work? I guess no.

Comment: If I remember correctly, we still use this method with Firefox 33, so it should still work properly.